# First time on the site so I will preemptively counter your "welcomes" with "thanks," however

Tags: discussion

Can anyone tell me how you reply to other people's answers?

So all I see is the "link" and "edit" options down there but I also see lots of comments on the actual answers.

Come on, making new users go through ten different "Oops, you made yet ANOTHER mistake" isn't likely to encourage them to stay very long.

Site improvement suggestion:

1. Give people all of the required information for making a post right on the page so they don't have to go through all of this just to get a question asked.
2. If you don't want new users to create new tags, don't make them or at least give them a good list to choose from. How am I supposed to know what good tags to use? Provide some tags specific to THIS site instead of Drupal-specific. This is not a Drupal related question, but a Stackexchange one.

Comment: Maybe the FAQ's will help you: [drupal.stackexchange.com/faq](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq), [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Answer (score 2):

In order to post comments on questions and answers you need to have a reputation of at least 50.  See the [privileges page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/privileges) (specifically the [comment everywhere privilege](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment)) for more info.

It is also of real benefit to read through the FAQs, as @marcvangend commented above, to get accustomed with the site and its workings.

Answer (score 0):

> If you don't want new users to create new tags, don't make them or at least give them a good list to choose from.

The tags used for questions are all listed in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags; every tag has a short explanation of what its purpose is. If you still don't understand when a tag should be used, you can check the other questions using that tag and, if you still don't understand that, you can ask a question on the meta site (here).

> Provide some tags specific to THIS site instead of Drupal-specific.

*Drupal Answers* is specific for questions about Drupal; that is the reason why [c++](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) will never be used on *Drupal Answers*. If you are asking on *Drupal Answers* (the main site) a question about the site itself, then you are asking it in the wrong place, as questions about an SE site are asked on its meta site (this very site); that is the reason a tag like [discussion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) will never be used on the main site, but [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) is used here.